# Maven surefire-plugin different version at execution than in pom

Tags: java, maven, testing, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to move from JDK 8 --> JDK 11 and sure enough maven surefire-plugin is failing. So I know that I need to change it's version to 2.21.0 or above that and I already did so. The version is only referenced in one pom so everything should be fine and even intellIJ says that I am using version 2.22.2.
The thing is I am when I run a mvn clean install -U or mvn test, or a mvn clean then mvn compile-test and lastly a test I am still getting error referencing:
`Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1:test (default-test) on project modular-index-composer: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1:test failed.: NullPointerException`

How is it even possible? I am 100% sure that the project must have a version of 2.22.2. Is there any other way where it could be set?

Comment: First where is the relationship between surefire and your upgrade JDK8->JDK11? Furthermore without any pom file it's simply impossible to even guess what's wrong or might be wrong... Why not using the most recent version of maven-surefire-pugin ?

Comment: Surefire plugin breaks with 2.20.1 versions or anything below that for jdk 11. If you search for it you can see plenty of people having this problem.

Comment: Surefire itself usually not but it might depend on the usage of different versions of unit testing framework (junit 4.X, junit jupiter, testng?) ...

Answer (score 0):

Kinda obvious/dumb solution:
So the project is made up of multiple modules, and there is a "parent" module that has most of the dependencies with their versions. I changed the sunfire version in this modules pom, and nothing seemed to be changing. (Eventhough intellij showed the correct newer version for the plugin)

So I decided to just exclude the parent pom and add the sunfire plugin with its version directly into my module. And behold it worked.
The issue is probably something with the parent pom, my guess would be that my module is not pulling from the correct parent pom version or it mixed it up somehow.

Comment: If it is a multi module build you have a parent where you can define the version via pluginManagement for all childs... nothing to do with dependency...

Comment: My bad, I might have not written it clearly enough.
My module has a sunfire plugin, but it's version is given in the parent pom. I changed that version (in the parent pom) but nothing seemed to change in my module, it was still the older version... Once I directly added this plugin with the correct version to my module and excluded the one in the parent it worked. So probably my module is pulling from a different parent pom or something like that.